# Using the Parseval Identity to compute $ \sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{(4n^2-1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, summation, self-learning, fourier-series

> **Parseval's Identity**: For continuous $f: [- \pi , \pi] \to \mathbb{R}$
>
> $$ \sum_{n=- \infty}^{+ \infty} |c_n|^2 = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{ - \pi}^{ \pi} |f(x)|^2dx, \text{ where } c_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \pi}^{ \pi} f(x)e^{-inx}dx$$
>
> ---
>
> **Problem**: Using Parseval's Identity, consider the **even** function $f:= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} \sin \left( \frac{x}{2} \right), \  x \in [0, \pi] $ to compute the sum: $$\sum_{n =1}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{(4n^2-1)^2} $$

This is my first attempt to work with *Parseval's Identity* and *Fourier coefficients*. I did read this similar question beforehand, but it didn't help me to complete this task  [Use Fourier series for computing $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108834/use-fourier-series-for-computing-sum-n-1-infty-frac12n-12).

**My approach**: I will merely write down the results, I did all the calculations by hand on paper and then double-checked by using Mathematica. Writing out the entire process would only make this post blow up in length further.

To get the Fourier Coefficients I did integrate using only the definition as above, I first did look at the case for $n=0$. I got $$ c_0 = \frac{1}{2}$$
for the case $ n \neq 0$ I applied integration by parts two times and after a pretty tedious process I did end up with $$c_n = \frac{ in \cos (n \pi)}{4n^2-1}= \frac{in (-1)^n}{4n^2-1} $$
Which was a very satisfying result, because now I have $$|c_n|^2 = \frac{n^2}{(4n^2-1)^2}$$which somewhat looks very close to what I am supposed to get, except for that annoying $n^2$ in the numerator.

Finally evaluating $$ \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \pi}^\pi |f(x)|^2dx = \frac{1}{32}(8+ \pi^2)$$

**Doubts and Questions**:

- I have a feeling that my method of integrating was wrong, because I did not make use of $f$ being even which would mean that $f(-x)=f(x)$ and therefore integration from $- \pi, \pi$ would result to be twice the original integral with bounds from 0 to $2 \pi$
- - I did not make use of the statement $f$ is even, because when I plot $f$ it does not look even at all to me, so I wonder about this statement in general. I suppose it has something to do with the definitions of Fourier Coefficients and their application to $A$-periodical Functions.
- If the above procedure would happen to be right, how could I get the final statement? More precisely formulated, how would I possible get from $$ \sum_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} \frac{n^2}{(4n^2-1)^2}$$ to the Sum that starts from $1$ and ends at $\infty$ ?

Comment: Are you sure of your calculations?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal, unfortunately I have to answer with no, you will find it under my "Doubts and Questions" section that I am not 100% positive about my calculations. My main issue is the statement that $f$ is even which, after plotting the graph of $f$, makes no geometric sense to me whatsoever. I could not teach Mathematica to consider $f$ being even, but all the above Calculations were done by hand and then checked in Mathematica CAS.

Comment: To use Parseval's Identity you need to have a function defined on a symmetric interval. In your question you just gave $f$ defined on $[0,\pi]$. How are you extending it to $[-\pi, \pi]$?

Comment: @GitGud, I did not extend it in my question if you wanted to know that. If you wanted to hear about a possible approach to extend the above function to the interval $[- \pi, \pi]$ I have to confess that I do not know, I could take twice the values maybe or use periodicity of $\sin$

Comment: @Spaced You need to extend it, I think. It's hard to believe that they want you to take $f$ defined by the same expression in $[-\pi, \pi]$. It's possible, but unlikely, in my opinion. have you tried to put the sum in mathematica just to check?

Comment: Thanks for your response @GitGud, I guess with the sum you meant the one I have given in my last row, by Mathematica, this sum would converge, which is indeed no good sign. So far I haven't heard about "extending definitions" or ever used it, nor seen it in class. Although it sounds to me like something that can easily be done. I am sorry if the problem is unclear in that manner, but its a 1:1 copy from my Problem Set (optional - not accredited problem), I will try to consult my tutor. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Is your function an even function?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal, yes the function is supposed to be even as defined on $[0, \pi]$, I did highlight that again in my question.

Comment: @Spaced I was gonna answer your question, but before doing that I checked if the sum was right. It isn't as you can see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28n%5E2%2F%284n%5E2-1%29%5E2%29+from+n%3D-inf+to+n%3D%2Binf), but it's close. Can you check if you can correct the error somewhere? If you can't, ping me and I'll help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making use of the fact that $f$ is an **even** function, we extend $f$ as follows:  \begin{align}f:& \begin{cases} [0, \pi] &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\x  & \longmapsto  \displaystyle \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} \sin \left( \frac{x}{2}\right) \end{cases} \tag{given} \\\\\\ f:& \begin{cases} [ - \pi, \pi] & \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ x & \longmapsto \begin{cases} f(x), & 0 \leq x \leq \pi \\ f(-x), & - \pi \leq x \leq 0  \end{cases} \end{cases} \tag{extended} \end{align} 
With this definition of $f$ we have the property that for $ n \neq 0$ *(for $n = 0$ analogous)* 
\begin{align}c_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \pi}^{ \pi} f(x) e^{-inx}dx = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \pi}^0 \underbrace{f(x)}_{=f(-x)} e^{-inx}dx + \int_0^\pi f(x)e^{inx}dx \end{align}
A simple **substitution** $u=-x$ for the first integral leads to:
 \begin{align}c_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^\pi f(x) \underbrace{\left( e^{inx}+ e^{-inx} \right)}_{= 2 \cos (nx)}dx \end{align}
which would finally lead to the correct, symmetric Fourier coefficients \begin{align} c_n = \frac{1}{8n^2-2}= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{4n^2-1} \text{ with } c_{-n}=c_n\end{align}
Computing in a likewise manner $$ \frac{1}{ 2 \pi} \int_{- \pi}^\pi |f(x)|^2dx = \frac{\pi ^2-8}{32} $$ leads to the **final result**: $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4n^2-1}= \frac{\pi^2-8}{16} $$