# Prove that $\int_R \frac{1}{1-x^2y^2} \,dx \,dy = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

The region $R$ is the unit square with corners at $(0,0), (1,0), (0,1)$ and $(1,1)$.

The idea is to consider the geometric series.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do you know a geometric series whose sum is $1/(1-a)$?

Comment: Yeah. $1 + a + a^2 + ...$

Comment: Some post about the same series (but not the same method): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108834/use-fourier-series-for-computing-sum-n-1-infty-frac12n-12 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454960/how-can-we-show-frac-pi28-1-frac132-frac152-frac172

Comment: A proof of this is given in Aigner, Ziegler: Proofs from the BOOK;
[p.37](https://books.google.com/books?id=OuklBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA37) in the third edition,
[p.55](https://books.google.com/books?id=2iI9BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA55) in the fifth edition.

Comment: Hint $xy\leq 1$ inside the unit square...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I collect all hints and write down the answer.

1. We use the formula for sum of a geometric series as following
   $$
   \frac{1}{1-x^2y^2} = 1 + x^2y^2 +x^4y^4 + \dots.
   $$
2. Then we have
   $$
   \int\limits_{R}\frac{1}{1-x^2y^2}\, dxdy = 
   \int\limits_{R}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}y^{2n}\, dxdy = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty 
   \int\limits_{R}x^{2n}y^{2n}\, dxdy.
   $$
3. And $\int\limits_{R}x^{2n}y^{2n}\, dxdy = \int_0^1\int_0^1x^{2n}y^{2n}\, dxdy = 1/(2n+1)^2$.
4. Finally 
   $$
   \int\limits_{R}\frac{1}{1-x^2y^2}\, dxdy = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}.
   $$